# How use navigate properly

Tags: react-native

I'm Making a App with navigate. My component that make the navigate has this code:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Articles: { screen: ArticlesScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen},
    ModalProfile: { screen: ModalProfile},
},
{
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' }
 });

 export default AppNavigator;
```

The ArticlesScreen will mount first, calling `componentDidMount()` , when i call `this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')` inside the article screen (with a button) the navigate go to my Profile screen, calling the `componentDidMount()` function of my profile. When a call `this.props.navigation.navigate('Articles')`, the navigation go to ArticlesScreen, and not call the `componentDidMount()`. But when a call `this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')` again the `componentDidMount()` function of my profile will execute, and this is generating some problems.

In resume, why when i call ProfileScreen the page is mounting by zero, and my ArticlesScreen not? And how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` will be called only when a component gets mounted. If the component is already in the navigation history, when you navigate back to it, it doesn't get mounted again. So, `componentDidMount()` will not be called on them.

When you navigate back to a previously mounted component, any component mounted after the one you just navigated to will be unmounted. That means, when you navigate to `Articles` from `Profile`, `Profile` is unmounted. That is why going back to `Profile` is triggering `componentDidMount()` again.

Understanding the [Navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html) will help you here.

The [Example scenario](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html#example-scenario) makes it more clear.

> Consider a stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.
>
> When going back from B to A, componentWillUnmount of B is called, but componentDidMount of A is not because A remained mounted the whole time.